# What is best way to put Required Text in Select Box?

Tags: forms, webforms, ux-integration

I'm creating contact form. I have read Web form design guidelines and found tips to add optional or required text instead of putting asterisks. I have found the information in https://www.cxpartners.co.uk/our-thinking/web_forms_design_guidelines_an_eyetracking_study/. I want to put Required text in select box. I'm confused where to place the text in Select field. Can anyone suggest best place to put it?

[image: Form Field Design]

Comment: Does the "REQUIRED" flag remain in the text box once the user clicks on it and starts typing?

Comment: No it will disappear once user click on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it will disappear once user click on this

Support persistence is important, whether it's labels, flags, or hints.

So either leave the flag in the box when the user is typing:

[image: flag remains in box]

(The problem with this is if the entered text overlaps the flag.)

**OR**, place the flag outside the box:

[image: flag outside box]

Comment: I think Required Field outside the field is the best way to solve this, because it will work in the case of select box as well. What you think in the case of select box?

Comment: Yes, same. I typically place field support next to the label, but I like how you right aligned the REQUIRED flag better.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it outside the box would leave it with less visual noise and also would not be a problem in specific use cases (e.g. If you ever need to use and icon inside the box)

This is also a direct advice from Universal Design Center https://www.csun.edu/ ([https://www.csun.edu/universal-design-center/web-accessibility-criteria-required-fields#:~:text=Required%20fields%20should%20be%20indicated,the%20user%20activates%20the%20field.](https://www.csun.edu/universal-design-center/web-accessibility-criteria-required-fields#:%7E:text=Required%20fields%20should%20be%20indicated,the%20user%20activates%20the%20field.))

Points:
1 - Id insert it between parenthesis to make it secondary, "something about this" (Required).

I know you are already using the color to balance the weight, but make sure this is alright from an accessibility POV.

2 - Why are you shouting REQUIRED to the user?